# Get all checked hidden values from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview with checkbox. When some one selects checkboxes i want get all checked hidden values and save into database.Below is my grid.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBillableAssetDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="ListId">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />                                    
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="GridRow" Height="25px" />                          
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check AssetSubType" SortExpression="CheckAssetSubType">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAssetSubType" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("Select").ToString() == "1" ? true:false%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ListId" HeaderText="ListId" Visible="false">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" /> 
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetType" HeaderText="AssetType">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" /> 
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AssetSubType" HeaderText="AssetSubType">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" /> 
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Below is my Code behind i want store list values and CompanyId into database.

```
protected void btnSave_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int companyId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EntityId"]);
        List<int> listListId = new List<int>();

        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in grdBillableAssetDetails.Rows)
        {                              
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkAssetSubType");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {                   
                int ListId = (int)grdBillableAssetDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value;
                listListId.Add(ListId);
            }
        }

        DataAccess.SaveListTypes(companyId, listListId);        

        hdnPageStatus.Value = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        hdnErrMsg.Value = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Can any please help me.

Comment: I want to get checked row hidden values and all the checked values stored into DB.

Comment: Please post your code-behind (C# or VB.NET) where you have attempted to get all the checked values.

Answer (score 0):

Below an example vb.NET

```
For j = 0 To gridCallfile.Rows.Count - 2<br>
    If Convert.ToBoolean (grid.Rows(j).Cells(5).Value) Then<br>
    'your code here
end If
```

Comment: Cells (5) is the index of the column where the checkbox is